# How to get a Layout partially under another

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, layout, android-toolbar

```
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout 


xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
        android:elevation="0dp">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"/>

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/toolbar2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:background="@color/colorAccent"/>


        </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="-80dp"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        />
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>


<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigationView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_header"
    app:menu="@menu/menu_drawer"
    />
```

The frame layout contains my recycler view..

I've added a collapsing toobar layout for the linear layout

I'm trying to get the frame layout to halfway up the collaping toolbar layout

but This is the result I'm getting

[image]

what I want is..

[image]

If you have a better method to do this please feel free to help. Im a complete noobie..

I'm sorry for my lack of artistic expertise in the paint image....

Please Check the Answers below For solution If you have the same problem..I've solved mine using the same

Comment: `now the frame layout is completely below the yellow layout` If it is below the yellow layout, perhaps you need to give it some more margins? like the one I've added to my answer maybe?

Comment: I got it to work... ill remove the edit now...The answer I selected explained how to do it... Thank you for answering though. I really appreciate the effort..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add these attribute inside of your `FrameLayout`

```
            app:layout_anchor="@id/app_bar"
            app:behavior_overlapTop="45dp"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom"
```

**EDIT:**

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/contentView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">


        <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/app_bar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?attr/colorSurface">

            <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:id="@+id/collapsing"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@color/white"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/placeholder_200_dp"
                    android:background="@color/red"/>

            </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>


        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_anchor="@id/app_bar"
            app:behavior_overlapTop="45dp"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
                <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/rvAttendanceHistory"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_medium"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/margin_medium"
                    android:background="@drawable/card_white_design"
                    tools:listitem="@layout/item_student_attendance" />
            </FrameLayout>

    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

The Above layout will make my FrameLayout overlap by 45dp

[image: recyclerView with overlap]

Comment: hello yes, what is that layout anchor??

Comment: @SIMPLEGUY  check now i have updated code . and anchor view that this view should position relative to given id

Comment: I've tried this... still the same result.. I set the anchor and changed the overlap top values... nothing... Is it because im using two toolbars??

Comment: please mention what happens when you increase the overlapTop value?? does the frame layout go on top further or comedown..(in your project)

Comment: if you increase the overlapTop value. FrameLayout go top . Yes remove toolbar from this layout it will work

Comment: but I need that toolbar to open the navigation drawer...

Comment: use toolbar inside CollapsingToolbar

Comment: after putting the toolbar1 inside collasping toolbar and giving the linearlayout inside the collapsing toolbar a margin to get it below toolbar1  im getting the desired effect... Thank you so much...

Answer (score 0):

It's because of this line:

```
android:layout_marginTop="-80dp"
```

You need to remove this first then,

All you need to do is adding this line of code to the `FrameLayout`:

```
app:behavior_overlapTop="150dp"
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the `elevation` attribute on your views to set the Z axis elevation, which will allow those 2 surface to be at different elevations.